# Using Append tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, append

I installed the Append Feature to Layer (zipped tool). There was no error message. The Append tool is in the Plugins.

I can't add the tool to the Panel, it doesn't appear in the Panels/Toolbars when I right click.

I am trying to select a row from a Feature and Append it into eg PostGIS.

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gacarrillor/AppendFeaturesToLayer

Look at the

> Where to find the algorithm

section.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated.
I wasn't able to mark it as useful.